# Irradiance from balloon onto sensor

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, radiometry, photometry

I am new to radiometry and some of the concepts are confusing me. I want to calculate the irradiance on a sensor from a balloon which is half illuminated by the sun and half illuminated by diffuse scattering from the sky/ground. I'm assuming the balloon is spherical, that the sensor normal is pointing at the center of the balloon, and that each point will scatter diffusely according to Lambert's law. Let $I_S$ be the sun irradiance, $I_A$ be the atmospheric irradiance, $\theta_S$ be the angle between the $dA$ normal and the sun rays, and $\theta_d$ be the angle between the $dA$ normal and center of the detector
[image]